# Which article of the GDPR implies that one should use the BCC field in order not to dissiminate personal mail addresses?

Tags: gdpr

Which article of the [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) implies that one should use the BCC field in order not to dissiminate personal mail addresses when sending mails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Article 5(1)(f)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-5-gdpr/)

> processed in a manner that ensures appropriate security of the personal data, including protection against unauthorised or unlawful processing and against accidental loss, destruction or damage, using appropriate technical or organisational measures (‘integrity and confidentiality’).